# How to make a bootstrap left and right column static

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 bootstrap column next to each other. I want the left and right column to be static and only the middle one must scroll.

I have tried making the columns fixed, but that changes the width of the column and if I make the right column fixed, then it gets shoved to the left of the page.

Is there another way to make it fixed without the fixed attribute?

Here is an image of my page.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class=" col col-sm-2 leftBar" style="padding: 10px;">

    <div style="padding: 10px 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #87CEEB;">

        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">List <span class="badge">4</span></a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;List Item 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;List Item 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;List Item 3</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;List Item 4</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class=" col col-sm-8 centreContent" style="padding: 10px;">

    <div style="padding: 10px 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #DCDCDC;">
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p>This is the content</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class=" col col-sm-2 rightBar" style="padding: 10px;">

    <div style="padding: 10px 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #87CEEB;">
        <p>This is the Right Bar</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: if you position RightBar on the right, position fixed will do just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/9zgeqv3s/ plus a bootstrap offset on a central column

Comment: Thanx @GL.awog. This worked the way I wanted it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9zgeqv3s)

if you position RightBar on the right, position fixed will do just fine.  plus a bootstrap offset on a central column:

```
<div class=" col col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 centreContent" style="padding: 10px;">....</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in two ways...

make left side bar and right sidebar fixed.
 for left bar

```
position : fixed;
left:0;
top:50px;
```

for right bar

```
position :fixed;
right:0;
top:50px;
```

or

You can apply this CSS to middle div..

```
max-heght:750px;
overflow-x:auto;
```

Comment: If you make those two columns fixed, it will take them out of the flow that the floats are using. You'll need to add 'col-sm-offset-2' to the middle column to account for the missing space when you changed to 'display: fixed'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, wrap your columns in a `.row` and in a `.container-fluid`.

Then create a new class called (for example) `.fixed-top` with property: `position: fixed;`. And apply this class to the left and right columns.

Then add the bootstrap offset column class `.col-**-offset-*`, to the center and right columns, respectively. (In your case: `.col-sm-offset-2` and `.col-sm-offset-10`).

Check this example with your code: http://www.bootply.com/RhXeray5xT